# Pdf reader having feature to play animations

Tags: 14.04, pdf, animations

I wonder if there is any pdf viewer and/or reader for `Ubuntu 14.04` to play animation of plots (Fig. 7, page 4 and page 9) in [knitr-graphics.pdf](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/graphics/) . Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks